# <style> and <script> tags are displayed physically on page

Tags: css, tags

i have very weird problem. If i put style or script tag on page, the browser sees them as html elements. In other words they are displayed, printed on page physically. Bottom code is shown in browser, on page, when i start my project. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I think you have unclosed tag. You should post whole code what you have.

Comment: Check for small errors like `<stle>` in the tags

Comment: @Sergio If `<style>` (unclosed only) is missing nothing will appear in browser.

Comment: I have already tried that, and i did not mention above, the problem is only in chrome, and if my elements have display:inline-block property

Comment: So, post your code here, that we can help you.

Comment: then you need to show us your code

Comment: @C-Link, yes. I pressed up-vote on your comment, and added another possibility.

Comment: @user1797770 does the browser shows other html codes or only css codes?

Comment: Wait a bit, it is a large project, i am looking for a small page

Comment: Please use http://jsfiddle.net to post snippets.

Comment: @C-Link the browser shows style and script tags if i put them on page

Comment: And in project i have user controls, only few aspx pages

Comment: And the problem is only if i use display:inline-block

Comment: without a link or code a doubt this question will get answered.

Comment: I tried to post code, but it has more characters than allowed :)

Comment: It is very big project

Comment: Sorry! see what you are missing. We could not help you without code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your CSS code, you probably set `display: inline-block` on `head`, `style`, and `script` elements, possibly due to the use of the universal selector `*`. By default, those elements are not displayed (they have implied `display: none`), but on many browsers, this can be changed with CSS. It’s normally not useful, but possible.

Comment: I already tried that with display:none :) And yes, your are right, in my css i have inline block class, and every child of an element with that class gets display property set to inline-block, due to white spaces problem with cross browser developing. Anyway, i did what i was avoiding the whole time. Solved it with some javascript code.

Comment: In the other hand, if displaying it is your goal, trying to do so in `body` rather than `head` might make things simpler for you.

Answer (score 9):

Just manually add inline `display: none` to those tags.
That would make it work.

Like, make your `<script>` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" style="display: none">
    //Some JS here
</script>
```

and `<style>` as

```
<style type="text/css" style="display: none">
    /* Some CSS */
</style>
```

Works pretty much on every browser (including IE8), not the best way since if they are being displayed, it means your CSS has some hole in it.

Comment: I already tried that with display:none :) And yes, your are right, in my css i have inline block class, and every child of an element with that class gets display property set to inline-block, due to white spaces problem with cross browser developing. Anyway, i did what i was avoiding the whole time. Solved it with some javascript code.

Comment: style="display: none" is best put inside inside of the <style> inner text </script>.

Answer (score 0):

Validate your page for unclosed tags: http://validator.w3.org/