# Adding a javascript function and removing it from the HTML instantly

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to add a `script` element to the HTML from the PHP code and instantly remove it so it won't be visible in the HTML. The script only contains things to execute at the same moment and not functions. Generally, I'm trying to replicate `ASP.NET`s `runat` property, so I'll be able to set values of elements (inputs for now) right from the PHP code.

This is what I tried so far (which I found in a different question, with some changes of mine) and it adds the script properly, but won't remove it.

```
function JSSetValue($id, $value) // Input 'value' only
{
    echo '<script>
          var input = document.getElementById("' . $id . '");
          input.value = "' . $value . '"
          </script>';
    $html = <<<HTML
...
HTML;
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $script = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script');
    foreach($script as $item)
    {
        $item->parentNode->removeChild($item); 
        break;
    }

    $html = $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: Stupid idea: Make the modification server side. Really scripts are already invisible to the user unless they click view source. If they click view source, they see the original html. There is no point in removing scripts from the live document (it certainly wont hide the script from the user if they try hard enough to retrieve it).

Comment: If you're using PHP just create the page with the input value set server side. It's simple and clean :)

Comment: If you goal is to protect your js files consider Minification. It makes them very hard to read and someone would have to go great lengths to make sense of them.

Comment: And if I first create the input element (with `echo`) and then want to set its value, isn't it easily possible like `ASP.NET`?

Comment: And I'm not trying to protect my js files, it just won't look neat because sometimes I `echo` the scripts in the middle of a table for example..

Comment: Script tags don't render as anything in the browser. Unless you manually inspect element, they are hidden.

Comment: If they are, you can hide them with CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182211/style-and-script-tags-are-displayed-physically-on-page

Comment: I want to remove them, so they won't be visible when inspecting elements.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone who were trying to help. Anyway, I found a solution to my question, which is this:

```
function JSSetValue($id, $value) // Input 'value' only
{
    echo '<script id="phpjs">
          var input = document.getElementById("' . $id . '");
          input.value = "' . $value . '";
          document.getElementById("phpjs").remove();
          </script>';
}
```

It adds the script and removes it, so it won't be visible when inspecting elements anymore.